# How do I import all scripts in a folder and use them as functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my file structure:

```
test.py
funcs/
   a.py
   b.py
   c.py
```

I'm trying to import **all** files inside `funcs` into `test.py` and be able to call them as functions, for example:

```
# test.py
import ...
a()
```

```
# a.py
print("foo")
```

Then running `test.py` would print `foo`.
I tried `from funcs import *` but I got a NameError because "`a is not defined`". I only got it to work this way:

```
# test.py
from funcs import a, b, c
a.foo()
```

```
# a.py
def foo():
   print("foo")
```

However, I would prefer if the script itself imported everything inside `funcs` rather than me specifying it each time I add a new script, and not having to add `.foo` in order to call `a.py` from `test.py`.

Comment: Modules aren't callable. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Could you give more context? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). For example, maybe it would be better to make `a`, `b`, and `c` into functions and put them into a script called `funcs.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
import funcs

funcs.a.foo()
```

This will import the entire module and call a.foo() from funcs

Answer (score 0):

just create an empty `__init__.py` in the `funcs` directory. then you can import functions like so:

```
from funcs.a import foo
```